# How to declare different methods with the same function name using parameter of List type

Tags: java

In our project, I want to declare two functions with same function name, same input parameters. The parameter type is List and the type of the elements are different of ObjectId and String which will result compile errors. let's see the examples below:

```
public List<T> get(List<? extends ObjectId> ids)
{
    ...
}

public List<T> get(List<? extends String> ids)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Java does not keep generic type at runtime, so this would not work. You can assign different names to your methods, or try to play with first element of the list, using instanceof, or provide other data in your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work around**

Just extends your different list with different name like this

```
    public class MethodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void print(Integers list) {

    }

    public void print(Strings list) {

    }
}

class Strings extends ArrayList<String>
{}

class Integers extends ArrayList<Integer>
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each method processes the List in the same way then I suppose that you **could** use one single method `public List<T> get(List<Object> ids)` and then check to see what type of things the List has in it within the method.

Even if they don't process the List in the same way you could still do something like:

```
if (ids.get(0) instanceof Integer){
    //do something
} else if (ids.get(0) instanceof String){
    //do something else
} else {
    //do yet another thing
}
```